# How to suppress eXist-db betterForms CSS?

Tags: exist-db, xforms-betterform

I wonder if it is possible to suppress eXist-db betterForms CSS.

I have googled for it, and the solution I have found [here](https://betterform.wordpress.com/faq/) was to add the CSS class `no-bf-css` to the body element the HTML page, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

To disable betterFORM in eXist:

Comment out or delete all betterFORM's servlets, filters and mapping in

```
    $EXIST_HOME/webapp/WEB_INF/web.xml
```

Comment out or delete betterFORM's resource-servlet in

```
    $EXIST_HOME/webapp/WEB_INF/controller-config.xml
```

(Adapted from Evgeny Gazdovsky's post to exist-open on May 4, 2013, archived at http://markmail.org/message/2mbnfzzmhqepc5zz.)

Comment: I think that way i would be disabling betterFORM engine and i just would like to surpress its default css

Comment: Ah, I see. Could you provide more information about your precise scenario: eXist version, and an example of a page that causes betterFORM's CSS to be inserted without having been declared? I'm not a betterFORM user, just an eXist user, so perhaps a more direct route to an informed answer would be to write to the betterform-user mailing list at https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/betterform-users.